# Edit Auth0 Custom Database Login Rule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, callback, auth0

This is the standard working version of auth0 custom database login connection with MONGODB,

```
function login(email, password, callback) {
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb@3.1.4').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://user:'+configuration.MONGO_PASSWORD+'@cluster0-2uci2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');


client.connect(function (err) {
if (err) return callback(err);

const db = client.db('db-name');
const users = db.collection('users');

users.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
  if (err || !user) {
    client.close();
    return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
  }

  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {
    client.close();

    if (err || !isValid) return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));

    return callback(null, {
        user_id: user._id.toString(),
        nickname: user.nickname,
        email: user.email
      });
  });
});
```

});
}

I am attempting to edit this to check against the username field as well as shown below,

```
function login(email, username, password, callback) {
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb@3.1.4').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://user:'+configuration.MONGO_PASSWORD+'@cluster0-2uci2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

client.connect(function (err) {
if (err) return callback(err);

const db = client.db('test');
const users = db.collection('users');

users.findOne({$or: [ {email: email }, {username: username }] }, function (err, user) {
  if (err || !user) {
    client.close();
    return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
  }

  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {
    client.close();

    if (err || !isValid) return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));

    return callback(null, {
        user_id: user._id.toString(),
        nickname: user.nickname,
        email: user.email
      });
  });
});
```

});
}

However I get a callback is not a function error. I am relatively new to javascript so I am not sure if I am able to edit the code the way I did, could someone please help? Thank you in advance!